# find the equation of the locus of a moving point which is always equidistant from the y-axis and the point (-6,4)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Do you know how to solve its equation? Already solved some locus problems that gives points but not in the y or x axis problems.

Answer (score 1):

If the point is $(a,b)$, its distance from the $y$ axis is $a$ and its distance from $(-6,4)$ is ??? Equate these and you have your equation.  It should be a parabola-this is one definition of a parabola.

Comment: so i will get an equation (x+6)*2 + (y-4)*2 = (x+0)*2? i got the answer y*2 + 12x - 8y + 52 in that equation. i have the answer here in the book but i don't know if i'm doing right or wrong

Comment: Yes, but you should have $=0$ to make an equation.  You need to convince yourself that you have not introduced an extraneous solution by squaring, but you haven't.  A plot is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%5E2-8y%2B12x%2B52%3D0)

Comment: i forgot, need to equate it to 0. ill try solving more problems to be familiarize

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x, y)$ be the unknown point. It's distance from the $y$ axis is given by $|x|$. It's distance from the point $(-6, 4)$ is given by $$d = \sqrt{(x - (-6))^2 + (y - 4)^2}$$

Now put $|x| = d $, and you're done, though you could, of course, simplify the equation:

$$x^2 = (x + 6)^2 + (y - 4)^2$$ and then simplify a bit more.

Comment: okay sir, i got the answer using that equation x*2 = (x+6)*2 + (y-4)*2, cancelling the squareroot to get it, if the question is always equidistant to x axis then its equals to y*2 too? vice versa